# Why const variable is lvalue in C++?

Tags: c++

I've started learning C++ via [this page](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/).

The concepts of rvalue and lvalue were confusing for me, especially this:

> Note: const variables are considered non-modifiable l-values.

I don't understand that const variable can be lvalue. Is there any example code that the const variable is used as lvalue in practice? I see no difference between rvalue and *non-modifiable* lvalue.

Comment: What exactly do you believe about a `const` object that prevents it from being an lvalue? What does "lvalue" mean to you?

Comment: I thought that the term "lvalue" means which can be at the leftside of assignment statement.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Both `a[i]` and `*(p+1)` are lvalues (unless `a` is an rvalue, in which case `a[i]` is an xvalue).

Comment: @JerryJeremiah your comment is completely wrong . lvalues and rvalues are expressions ,  either might designate a named or unnamed object,  and being expressions they "exist" as compilation constructs only.  You're mixing up objects with expressions .

Comment: `const` tells you if a variable can be modified or not. rvalue/lvalue tells you the value category. Both rvalues and lvalues can be modified. I don't really understand why an rvalue and a non-modifiable lvalue would be the same. You are comparing two different things that are not really related.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you have statement like this

```
const int con=10;     //con is non-modifiable l-value
```

- you can not modify value of con .
- But con has address(&con).

So it is non-modifiable l-value.

code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(void)
{
    const int con=10; //con is non-modifiable l-value
    std::cout<<con;
}
```

Comment: That's not what the question is asking about.

Comment: @ L. F     does updated answer is ok?

Comment: It's better, but including the definition of lvalues and rvalues to explain the significance of the code would be better.